# Removing random raphael elements from canvas

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io, raphael

I'm working with raphaeljs and socketIO for a realtime data presentation. I have circles representing nodes on my canvas and they're stored in `nodeStatus` object as `nodeStatus[id].obj` where "id" can be "101", "102", etc., I'm trying to implement a function to randomly remove previously-drawn circles(nodes) from the client-side-browser's canvas.

The server side script which is used to send the nodeID & obj is this:  `socket.emit("randomNode",randomNode,nodes[randomNode]);`. randomNode contains the ID of the circle that I want to remove. nodes[randomNode] is the object that stores the information on that node.

Here's the relevant part in my client-side html. (nodeID is the id of the circle(node) that I want to remove(from my canvas/paper) and obj is the corresponding object)

```
socket.on("randomNode",function (nodeID, obj){
    nodes[nodeID] = obj;
    console.log(nodeID,obj);
    updateNodeStatus(nodeID);
    console.log(nodeStatus[nodeID]);
    nodeStatus[nodeID].obj.remove();
    nodeStatus[nodeID].idText.remove();
 });
```

The `nodeStatus[nodeID].obj.remove();` producing "TypeError: nodeStatus[id].obj is undefined" error.

`console.log(nodeID);` prints the expected values like "101", "102", etc., And `nodeStatus[102].obj.remove();` removes the "raphael object with id=101" from canvas. But `nodeStatus[nodeID].obj.remove();` doesn't work as it should. Can someone point out where I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Any chance you could get a testing example on a jsfiddle  somehow, or at least more of the code around nodeStatus when its built. Especially do a console.log( nodeStatus[nodeID] ); you have that in your code there, but not actually what it outputs.

Comment: Can't get my codes on jsfiddle since it has server side ".js", server side "config.js" and client side ".html" for socket.io. I got it working, though. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
socket.on("randomNode",function (nodeID, obj){
    nodeStatus[nodeID].obj.remove();
    nodeStatus[nodeID].idText.remove();    
    nodes[nodeID] = obj;
    console.log(nodeID,obj);
    updateNodeStatus(nodeID);
    console.log(nodeStatus[nodeID]);
 });
```

It turns out that the raphael objects (saved in nodeStatus obj) have to be removed first. `updateNodeStatus(nodeID)` only updates the information on a certain node(node with id = nodeID) and thus `nodeStatus[nodeID].obj` or `nodeStatus[nodeID].idText` is undefined.